# Python Kivy build error on windows ubuntu

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

My environment:

```
python : 3.6.9
sys : Windows10 Ubuntu
```

my error:

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/jease/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/jease/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Android NDK found at /home/jease/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I know have lots of answer to solve this question, but i try lots of way too, but all of the ways i found had error too.

The way i try :

- change the buildozer.spec log_level to 2
- change  Android SDK to 19
- buildozer android clean and remake buildozer android debug

This is all of the error log

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/jease/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/jease/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/jease/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Android NDK found at /home/jease/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21'
# Cwd /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 27 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/jease/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
[INFO]:    Found NDK version 17c
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /home/jease/.local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named cython
[WARNING]: Cython for python3 missing. If you are building for  a python 3 target (which is the default) then THINGS WILL BREAK.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Found a single valid recipe set: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2 bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name myapp and requirements (python3, kivy)
[INFO]:    Dist contains the following requirements as recipes: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules () installed from pip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    hostpython3 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading libffi
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/libffi
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/libffi
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/libffi/libffi/archive/v3.2.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    libffi download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading openssl
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/openssl
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/openssl
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    openssl download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2_image download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-amalgamation-3150100.zip
[INFO]:    sqlite3 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading python3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python3
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    python3 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.9.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading setuptools
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/setuptools
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/setuptools
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-40.9.0.zip
[INFO]:    setuptools download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading six
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.10.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    six download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/6553ad4.zip
[INFO]:    pyjnius download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading android
[INFO]:    Skipping android download as no URL is set
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/1.11.1.zip
[INFO]:    kivy download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    # Building all recipes for arch armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    # Unpacking recipes
[INFO]:    Unpacking hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop
[INFO]:    hostpython3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/libffi/libffi/archive/v3.2.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    libffi is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking openssl for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/openssl/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    openssl is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_image is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-amalgamation-3150100.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    sqlite3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking python3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    python3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.9.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking setuptools for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-40.9.0.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    setuptools is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking six for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.10.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/six-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    six is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/6553ad4.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    pyjnius is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    -> running rm -rf /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/android-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android
[INFO]:    -> running cp -a /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/src /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/plat...(and 85 more)
[INFO]:    Unpacking kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/1.11.1.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/kivy-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    kivy is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    # Prebuilding recipes
[INFO]:    Prebuilding hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    hostpython3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    libffi has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for libffi[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    libffi already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding openssl for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    openssl has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_image has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_image[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    sdl2_image already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_mixer[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sqlite3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding python3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    python3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for python3[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    python3 already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding setuptools for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    setuptools has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding six for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    six has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    pyjnius has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for pyjnius[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    pyjnius already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding android for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    android has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/android-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android
[INFO]:    <- directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Prebuilding kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    kivy has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    # Building recipes
[INFO]:    Building hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Skipping hostpython3 (3.7.1) build, as it has already been completed
[INFO]:    Building libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi
[INFO]:    -> running autogen.sh
Exception in thread background thread for pid 10332:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/jease/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jease/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/jease/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/jease/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127:

  RAN: /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
/mnt/c/MinGW/bin/autoreconf: 175: exec: /mnt/c/MinGW/bin/autoreconf-2.68: not found


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1192, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 668, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 206, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 33, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 180, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/jease/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/jease/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/jease/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127:

  RAN: /mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
/mnt/c/MinGW/bin/autoreconf: 175: exec: /mnt/c/MinGW/bin/autoreconf-2.68: not found


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/mnt/c/Users/jease/Desktop/soft_work/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I need help...

Comment: Changing `log_level` to 2 is not a way to fix the problem. It is just a way to get more information logged. What does the log from look like after specifying `log_level` 2?

Comment: @JohnAnderson  It's the same of the error message

Comment: Looks like you need to install autoreconf